# Add Array to pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I need to iterate over a dataframe. In each iteration row.Text is converted into a vector-representation and stored as a numpy.ndarray (newData). Now i want to add a column (Vektoren) to the original dataframe and apply to each row the newData array

```
    for idx,row in data.iterrows():
        doc = nlp(row.Text)
        newData =doc.vector
        data.loc[idx,'Vektoren'] = newData
```

Unfortunatly i cant get it to work. what would be a better way instead of using iterrows?

I got it to work with a list:

```
    vectorList = []
    for idx,row in data.iterrows():
        doc = nlp(row.Text)
        newData =doc.vector
        vectorList.append(newData) 
    data['Vektoren'] = pd.Series(vectorList)
```

I am still wondering if there is a more elegant solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your solution concise with `map`

```
data['Vektoren'] = data['Text'].map(lambda s: nlp(s).vector)
```